# Installing jdk 1.4.2 on fedora 14

Tags: fedora, java

I am trying to install wsdgate,
In the installation they have recommended to use jdk 1.4.2,
I already have jdk 1.7 but I am not able to install JDK 1.4.2 on fedora 14.
I got error like this
`could not execute binary file`
can anyone please help me who has done something similar before?
what should i do to install jdk version 1.4 in my fedora?

Comment: What did you download? How did you install it? What caused this error? Copy-paste the commands you typed.

Comment: try with `chmod a+x your_binary_file`